# An error occurred in my client, but it's not from my client

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm developing a service with Vue.js. Recently, I've got errors like below image.
[image: The error from my client.]

Though, I'm using socket.io to connect server and client. But, Its initiator is not client, but chunk-vendors. I don't know how to solve this error. I've googled about this error, but I haven't got a clear answer.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is your local server running without errors?

Comment: @Agney Yeah, Actually It's in AWS. It works well, without any errors.